# Xcode 6 GM won't compile for iOS device, but is fine in simulator - odd error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a project that compiled just fine in XCode 6 beta, but now, in the GM, it won't compile for an iOS device, giving the error:

```
myController.m:393:9: No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'initialize:'
```

at this line:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

It still compiles absolutely fine for the simulators; I've also tried these fixes:

- Cleaned the whole project and re-built.
- Deleted all Derived Data from ~/Library/Developer/XCode
- Re-installed XCode
- Checked XCode preferences and pointed Command Line Tools location to XCode 6  (XCode 5 is still installed on the machine and it was pointing there)

...but with no luck.  Same error on compilation.

Help!  We're on a tight timescale with iOS8 now approaching, and this is a real headache.

PS: We're also using Cocoapods in the workspace, for what it's worth.

Comment: Did you upgrade the device to GM?

Comment: Yes, the device is running iOS 8 GM - no backups from iCloud or anything like that, vanilla install.

Comment: Did you try to restart you Mac? I had some weird issue with Xcode on "can't find iOS 8 simulator". A restart magically solve all the issue. May worth a try.

Comment: Yes, all restarted - still getting the error.  I'm going to totally remove CocoaPods to see if it's referencing some old framework headers or something; it's odd that it can't find the right headers for UIDevice, but only on this particular build target rather than when building for the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved this one after rather a lot of hair-pulling.  The app in question is an iOS 8 app, with an embedded Today Extension.

It turned out that, when adding the Today Extension, XCode had added a build setting:

> 'Enable Modules (C and Objective-C':  YES

Neither my project nor my containing app targets used this build setting, but setting it to YES caused issues to do with trying to link Frameworks automatically (and failing) and all sorts of related odd error messages that ultimately related to header files.

The problem was further compounded because there are source files that are members of both the containing app's target and also the Today Extension's target.

Hope this info helps somebody else.

[image]

Carl