# Xcode 6 compile error on device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, compiler-errors, xcode6, device

SUMMARY:

- I get a compile error on the device but not the simulator
- The error description is certainly not the root cause of the problem
- I think it has to do with standard imports of SDK classes
- It might have to do with having an iOS8 extension in the app
- There is a similar problem description on stackoverflow, but the
  solution does not work for me

I'm stuck with a strange problem in Xcode 6. The project compiles fine on the Simulator, but I get a compile error whenever I try to compile for the device.

The project has been created from a tabbar template (note: Xcode 6 project templates have no prefix file anymore by default) and consists of an iOS app and the new extension enhancements introduced in iOS8. Both the app and the extension should use some base classes, namely a class which uses AFNetworking for fetching data from the net.

As described in AFNetworking docs, I declared AF_APP_EXTENSION to be able to compile the extension.
I am not sure if any of this is related to the problem, just trying to throw some facts and hoping something rings a bell for someone.

Anyway, it is in AFNetworking where I get the build errors:
"No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'systemVersion'" in AFURLRequestSerialization.

When playing around with imports, for instance importing UIKit.h at some random points for trying, I sometimes (!) get a different error:

"No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'initWithData:'" in AFURLResponseSerialization.

Needless to say that these are these methods are declared since iOS 2.0. I think it has something to do with the new way of importing base classes and the lack of a prefix file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754324/xcode-6-gm-wont-compile-for-ios-device-but-is-fine-in-simulator-odd-error-me) is a so post describing, I think, exactly the same problem, but the solution, setting Enable Modules to NO, does not work at all for me, I get then 50+ compile errors about missing classes as UIResponder in AppDelegate and stuff.
I guess this is because the Enable Module setting is the replacement for the prefix imports? But I am really swimming here.

I tried cleaning, clean build folder, restart Xcode, restart Mac, add imports here and there, reading LLVM compiler settings in build settings.

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I assume you are running iOS 8 on your device, is this correct?  Also, have you tried to delete the app on your device and build it again with Xcode?

Comment: Yes, iOS 8 on an iPhone 5c. But I get the error even when no device is attached (just compiling for the default "iOS Device"). I never compiled successfully, it's a fresh project. I can't delete the app on the device, it was never on there in the first place.

Comment: Ok, how are you importing AFNetworking? Through CocoaPods, submodules, or importing it directly into your project?   I have experienced issues when using CocoaPods if the pods project is not set to use iOS 8 as the base SDK and the main project is using iOS 8, or vice versa.

Comment: Directly, dragging and dropping the AFNetworking folder into the project and "copy if needed". I still haven't figured out CocoaPods.

Comment: What it sounds like is happening is that your project has a header path misconfigured and AFNetworking isn't finding what it needs. If you haven't already, I would first try removing all of the AFNetworking code and updating to the latest version (2.4.1).  If you are really feeling adventurous, I would install CocoaPods because it helps to manage the header paths and keep your dependencies well in order.

Comment: Dear sashimiblade, thank you for your help. I did as you recommended, installing AFNetworking through CococaPods. It solved the issue (after some struggling with library paths). Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help out and that it's working for you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I fixed this by deleting the folders in DerivedData folder, specifically, the "ModuleCache" folder.